# Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments

Tags: nesting, optional-arguments

LaTeX seems to be having problems handling nested optional arguments. I've included a minimal code example that generates the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\termbad}[2][]{#2#1}
\newcommand{\termgood}[2][]{#2#1}

\newcommand{\up}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\dd}[1][]{#1}

\termgood{\up{Tart}}{Pop}
\termbad[\up{Tart}]{Pop}    

\termgood{\dd[Tart]}{Pop}
\termbad[{\dd[Tart]}]{Pop}
%\termbad[\dd[Tart]]{Pop}


\end{document}
```

If you run this code, it works. If you remove the `%` in the second to last line, it fails with:

```
Runaway argument?

Tart{Pop} \par \par \end {document}

!File ended while scanning use of \dd.
```

After further tinkering, I have discovered the problem: LaTeX is reading the `]` for the inner optional argument as the end of the outer optional argument and then passing a malformed argument in. So it is passing in `\dd[Tart` as the optional argument to `\termbad` instead of `\dd[Tart]`.

This still feels like a bug to me. Nesting braces in arguments works, brackets should as well. The following are workarounds:

- Enclose the inner optional argument in braces (as in the line before `%`).
- Redefine your inner function to require its argument instead of using optional arguments.
- Redefine your outer function to require its argument instead of using optional arguments.

Any one of the three works around the issue.

(Reposted here; question was originally posted to stackexchange and then closed instead of being migrated.)

Comment: As far as I can see, the main problem is that LaTeX doesn't define the notion of nested optional arguments. This is why different implementations have different semantics.

Comment: [syntax - \] inside an optional argument - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument) has a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When TeX reads arguments, then TeX only checks for matching curly braces (characters with catcode 1 and 2). Square brackets are not special in this sense. The *first* `]` that is not hidden inside curly braces is taken as the end of the optional argument. Therefore an additional set of braces is the usual solution:

```
\foo[{\bar[...]}]{...}
```

It is only a bug, if this does not work, e.g. if the definition passes optional arguments to other commands:

```
\def\foo#1#2{\bar[#1]{#2}}
```

This should be

```
\def\foo#1#2{\bar[{#1}]{#2}}
```

Then `#1` may contain square brackets, especially `]`.

Comment: Worth noting that `xparse`-defined functions do not suffer from this

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm looking at xparse now, since I'm using some complex code to create a highly linked and formatted document. This may solve a few of the problems I've been having.

Comment: an answer explicitly showing how `xparse` is used has been posted at [How do I nest a command with an optional argument?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304461/579)