# Russian matryoshka doll of optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

Why this not work. I suspect an expansion problem ...

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\foo}[1][foo]{#1}
\newcommand{\Fbox}[1][bla]{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}

\Fbox[\foo[bla]]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a FAQ: `\Fbox[{\foo[bla]}]`

Comment: Please flag it as needed or tell me what to do. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to say that the title is very creative, so creative that no one will ever come up with this keyword and be lead to here by search engine.

Comment: But maybe some one will become a `latex` user searching after russian popular art ? who knows ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your square brackets are ambiguous.

When your write `\Fbox[\foo[bla]]` the `\Fbox` macro thinks that its' (optional) argument is `\foo[bla`. Then `\foo` tries to execute with argument `[bla` so it complains because its' argument does not conform to the expected syntax.

As egreg says, to fix the problem you need to write `\Fbox[{\foo[bla]}]`.

As Symbols says in the comments, if you use the `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [xparse package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) then your syntax becomes legal because xparse is slightly smarter in how it matches brackets/delimiters. In full detail, this works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{O{foo}}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand\Fbox{O{bla}}{\fbox{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \Fbox[\foo[bla]]
\end{document}
```

The xparse package is really cool. You can use it define macros with many optional arguments, in any order you like, with or without defaults, with different delimiters, with stars, with bells, ... OK, not with bells but it is one of my favourite packages:) As another silly example,

```
\NewDocumentCommand\fock{D|>\lambda}{|#1\rangle}% optional argument between |...>
```

defines a macro that, by default, produces the same as `|\lambda\rangle` and where the optional arguments are given as `\fock|\mu>`, which expands to `|\mu\rangle`. (Of course, this should always be used in math-mode.

Comment: Would you like to say something about `xparse`? It is not well-explained in egreg's comment and this is a good chance.

Comment: @Symbol1 Good point. You are obviously more adept at reading egreg's comments than I am as I see no mention of xparse there:)

Comment: For about 20 seconds I was (also) wondering where the comment goes. Turns out it becomes **This question already has an answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments)**