# How do I nest a command with an optional argument?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'm having problems making a normalizer command that can nest. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\nrml}[2][]{N_{#1}(#2)}

\begin{document}
$\nrml[\nrml{H}]{J}$
\end{document}
```

which works fine, but when I try `$\nrml[\nrml[G]{H}]{J}$` I get a bunch of error codes, the first one being ``Argument of \nrml has an extra }.'' How can I fix this?

Edit: originally posted incorrect code, fixed.

Edit 2: It looks like `$\nrml[{\nrml[G]{H}}]{J}$` does what I'm trying to do, but it seems pretty ridiculous that I would need to surround an argument that's already indicated by square brackets by braces, and that is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define your command with `xparse`, the problem is taken care of automatically; note that you can also easily insert the subscript only if actually specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nrml}{om}{%
  N\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}(#2)%
}

\begin{document}

$\nrml[\nrml{H}]{J}$

$\nrml[\nrml[K]{H}]{J}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Enclose the outer optional argument in braces.  The issue is in the way that optional arguments are digested by LaTeX (see [Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\nrml}[2][]{N_{#1}(#2)}

\begin{document}
$\nrml[\nrml{H}]{J}$

$\nrml[{\nrml[G]{H}}]{J}$
\end{document}
```

[image]