# Flexible \IfStrEqCase statement

Tags: xstring

I am trying to use `xstring`'s `\IfStrEqCase` to switch between cases. It seems to work fine *except* for the case where the parameter for the switch is a macro *with* an optional parameter:

```
\MySwitch{$\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$}
```

The problematic line is commented out in the MWE. Once this works as desired, the last line in the output should be duplicated:

[image]

The code within the `\MySwitch` is used often for different cases.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{o m}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{\text{#1: } #2}}%

\newcommand*{\MySwitch}[1]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {plain text}{text: #1}%
        {$x^2$}{math a: #1}%
        {$\MyMacro{a - b}$}{math b: #1}%
        {$\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$}{math c: #1}%
    }[Error: Invalid input: #1]%
}

\begin{document}
\MySwitch{plain text}

\MySwitch{$x^2$}

\MySwitch{$\MyMacro{a - b}$}

math c: $\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$%% <-- Following should produce this output

%\MySwitch{$\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$}% <--- This is the problem

\end{document}
```

Comment: One might argue that this is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments, although it's perhaps not obvious unless one knows the answer ...

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304458/how-do-i-nest-a-command-with-an-optional-argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is a 'classic' one: the definition of optional arguments used by the LaTeX kernel (and most hand-written code) doesn't count up' square brackets. You therefore need to make sure that any place where optional arguments are nested is done with 'protection':

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{o m}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{\text{#1: } #2}}%

\newcommand*{\MySwitch}[1]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {plain text}{text: #1}%
        {$x^2$}{math a: #1}%
        {$\MyMacro{a - b}$}{math b: #1}%
        {$\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$}{math c: #1}%
    }[{Error: Invalid input: #1}]% CHANGE IS HERE
}

\begin{document}
\MySwitch{plain text}

\MySwitch{$x^2$}

\MySwitch{$\MyMacro{a - b}$}

math c: $\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$%% <-- Following should produce this output


\MySwitch{$\MyMacro[optional]{a - b}$}% <--- This is the problem

\end{document}
```

Notice that I've added a pair of braces *inside* the optional argument so that `#1` is 'safe' even if it itself contains `[ ... ]`.

Where everything is set up by `xparse` this issue doesn't arise as it uses a definition for optional arguments that *does* match up square brackets: as a  result, no extra steps are required.

Comment: Is there a simple fix to use `\mathrm` as in `\MySwitch{$\MyMacro[optional]{\mathrm{a} - b}$}`. I am getting a `\GenericError`.

Comment: @PeterGrill That's a different question and is because `\IfStrEqCase` is trying to `\edef` something containing `\mathrm`. Easiest solution is `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify\mathrm`, as this makes the command engine robust.