# lipsum as caption

Tags: captions, lipsum

The following fails to compile:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

giving the following error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 \caption{\lipsum[1]}
```

I assume the problem is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414) (and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470901)), but here I don't have nested square brackets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No issues with this MWE on up to date TeXLive 2019. BTW you can always use `\lipsum*[1]`, it will not emit a `\par` at the end.

Comment: Use `\LipsumPar`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\LipsumPar{1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks both. On my installation (TeXLive 2018) `\lipsum*[1]` gives the same error, and `LipsumPar` gives `Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: I always use \blindtext (blindtext package) in caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{\protect\lipsum[1]}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```