# Delimiter error using nested commands

Tags: macros, equations, errors, tex-core

I'm not an expert on TeX and I've run into a problem. I've been able to condense it into the following minimal working (or rather not working) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\E}{
    \@ifnextchar[{\Ea}{\mathbb{E}}
}
\newcommand{\Ea}[1][]{
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\Eb{#1}}{\mathbb{E}\left[#1\right]}
}
\newcommand{\Eb}[2]{
    \mathbb{E}\left[#1\,\middle|\, #2\right]
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \E[\E[X]{Y}]{Y}=\E[X]{Y}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I want this command `\E` to be usable as just `\mathbb{E}`. I want the first optional argument to be in square brackets and the second (even more optional) argument to be in curly brackets. I don't quite understand, why the above example doesn't work. I get the error "Missing delimiter (. inserted)." and the output looks like:
E[E[X|Y]]Y=E[X|Y]
where it is supposed to look like this
E[E[X|Y]|Y]=E[X|Y]
I also had some problems passing

```
\E[X_{n+1}]{X_1,\dots,X_n}
```

where I could identify `\dots` as the problem. This was fixable (why, I don't entirely understand) by writing

```
\newcommand{\Eb}[2]{
    \mathbb{E}\left[\nonexpanded{#1\,\middle|\, #2\right}]
}
```

However, this also doesn't solve the nesting-issue. I'm completely lost at this point, as to what is happening. Is there some way to solve this?

Comment: Wrap the inner one in group.

Comment: [nesting - Bug? LaTeX misparses nested optional arguments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78414/bug-latex-misparses-nested-optional-arguments)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99495/inside-an-optional-argument)

Comment: (... if you don't care about the internal details, search for "summary" and "conclusion" in the answer.)

Comment: Hm. Actually the first linked question above would be better as a duplicate target, as in the second case the OP  already know about the workaround.

Comment: you could define this in one line using xparse but note that even though xparse is now built in to latex you need to explicitly load the old version to enable the `g` type for optional `{}` arguments. `g`  is deprecated and not supported built in format version of xparse as it breaks all latex syntax conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Don't use optional `{`...`}`-delimited arguments.  Those are [*ugly*](https://www.texdev.net/2020/08/19/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-creating-document-commands)!

<sub><sup><sub>but if you must...</sub></sup></sub>

Either wrap the inner argument in braces :

```latex
\begin{equation}
  \E[{\E[X]{Y}}]{Y}=\E[X]{Y}
%    ^        ^
\end{equation*}
```

or use `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand \E { o !g }
  {%
    \IfValueTF{#1}%
      {%
        \mathbb{E}\left[#1%
          \IfValueT{#2}{\,\middle|\,#2}%
        \right]%
      }%
      {\mathbb{E}\IfValueT{#2}{{#2}}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \E[\E[X]{Y}]{Y}=\E[X]{Y}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \E[\E[X]]=\E[X]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \E\E{Y}=\E[X]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped! For some reason I never came across the xparse package. Very nice.