# Format is not applied in bibenvironment

Tags: biblatex

I have defined a very basic biblatex bibliography.

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{description}}
  {\end{description}}
  {\item[\nopunct\printnames{author}\addspace\printdate]}
\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\newline}
```

However, when trying to use my own format for the author names (`\printnames[myformat]{author}`) it will just print nothing, meaning it does not recognize it.
When outside the defbibenvironment it works fine and prints the authors with my format.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say what exactly is going on without a compilable example of what you are actually trying to run. So far I'd say chances are you're either running afoul of the fact that square brackets for optional arguments can only be nested if the inner ones are hidden in curly braces (try `\item[{\nopunct\printnames[myformat]{author}\addspace\printdate}]` see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78414/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864) or your `myformat` is somehow faulty.

Comment: @moewe it really just was the missing curly braces, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> Hard to say what exactly is going on without a compilable example of what you are actually trying to run. So far I'd say chances are you're either running afoul of the fact that square brackets for optional arguments can only be nested if the inner ones are hidden in curly braces (try \item[{\nopunct\printnames[myformat]{author}\addspace\printdate}] see also tex.stackexchange.com/q/78414/35864, tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495/35864) or your myformat is somehow faulty. –
> @moewe

it really just was the missing curly braces, thank you very much.